# `GNU is Not Unix` Grep Bug?

Tags: grep

(Title must have at least 15 characters. Damn.)

I'd like to filter the output of of `blkid` for UUIDs (`UUID="[^"]*"`) and I want to get a blank line for each line that doesn't have a UUID.
I'm doing:

```
sudo blkid | grep -e '^' -e 'UUID="[^"]*"'
```

or
   sudo blkid | grep -e '$' -e 'UUID="[^"]*"'

Grep does that right if I run it without the `-o` switch, but when I do use the `-o` switch, the matches for '^' '$' are gone. What I expect is a blank line for each line that doesn't have the UUID pattern. (=each line that only matches ^ (or $)).

Am I wrong to expect this or is this a grep bug? Can I achieve my goal with grep?

**EDIT--Sample Input**

This is what my `blkid` outputs. True story:

```
/dev/sdbX: UUID="foo" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/sdbY: UUID="bar" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/this_wont_have_an_uuid TYPE="DM_snapshot_cow" 
/dev/mapper/this_wont_have_an_uuid2 TYPE="DM_snapshot_cow"
```

(The following assumes `sudo blkid >| blkid` has been run)

`< blkid grep -e 'UUID="[^"]*"' -e '$'`

^This colors the UUID specs and matches every line:

`< blkid grep -e 'UUID="[^"]*"' -e '$' -o`

^This outputs:

```
UUID="foo"
UUID="bar"
```

(UUID-less lines are gone :( ).

Comment: Could you show an output of `blkid`? Currently it looks a bit complicated to predict the behaviour of grep without such info

Comment: Why do you rollback the revision? Having off topic comments and `edit` doesn't improve readability.

Comment: It can't be done with grep only. Use a bash/perl/ script, sed or vim in bash-mode. In vim it's done e.g using: `:g!/UUID="[^"]*"/s/.*//` There is a possibility to run vi in console mode

Comment: OK, so I checked the manual. And it is congruent with it: ` -o, --only-matching
              Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.`  The parenthesized expression is obviously key here--^ or $ is an empty, matched part.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal with `sed` if you don't find a `grep` version

```
blkid | sed '/UUID=/!s/.*//'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I checked the manual. And it is congruent with it:

`-o, --only-matching Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.`

The parenthesized expression is obviously key here--^ or $ is an »empty«, matched part.